# how to retrieve password from database and post on text box as *

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Please  Help I can't Retrieve My Password To Text box from Database

```
 protected void ClintUsr_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
            {
                ClintUsr.Columns[1].Visible = true;
                ClintUsr.Columns[3].Visible = true;
                ClintUsr.Columns[4].Visible = true;

                if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
                {
                    ImageButton Editimg = (ImageButton)e.CommandSource;

                    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)Editimg.NamingContainer;

                    LUser.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
                    txtusrname.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
            //        txtpass.Text = row.Cells[3].Text;
                    txtpass.Attributes["value"] = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[3]);
                    ddclientID.SelectedValue = row.Cells[4].Text;
                    ddactive.SelectedValue = row.Cells[6].Text;  
                    ddactive.DataBind();
                    bind();


                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                    ClintUsr.Columns[1].Visible = false;
                    ClintUsr.Columns[3].Visible = false;
                    ClintUsr.Columns[4].Visible = false;



                }
```

i am working on a web page that retrieve values from Database and show it on the web form. but in the Password Text box it shows empty. because it is set to Text Mode=Password. how can i show password sing java script.

Comment: not java script ...using asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Got Answer Thanks For Co-Ordination of all**

**Ans:**  `txtpass.Attributes["value"] = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[3].Text);`